# Tic Tac Toe Client Server Interaction

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, server, client

I am currently trying to code a Tic Tac Toe game in Java that is playable across networks. I'm using socket programming in Java and for the UI I am using JavaFX. Upon launching the server and 2 clients, the client connects to the server, pairs players and creates the game. When trying to execute the actual Tic Tac Toe game the GUI gets stuck. I believe it may have something to do with threading but after countless hours of trying different solutions I haven't been able to figure it out.

Below is a video of the issue 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCIxRkGJlCI&t=2s

My GitHub Repo:
https://github.com/Stinny/Tic-Tac-Toe

The issue I believe resides in the TicTacToeController.java class

Any info would be greatly appreciated!

This is my TicTacToeController Class

```
public class TicTacToeController implements Initializable {

private static Socket socket;
private static PrintWriter out;
private static BufferedReader in;
private static Image Circle = new Image("./Circle.png");
private static Image Cross = new Image("./Cross.png");
private static ImageView icon, opponentIcon;



@FXML
    Button topLeft, topRight, topCenter,
            midLeft, midCenter, midRight,
            botLeft, botMid, botRight;
    @FXML
    Button play;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }

    public void buttonClickHandler(ActionEvent evt) throws Exception{
            Button clickedButton = (Button) evt.getTarget();
            evt.getEventType();

            String button =((Control)evt.getSource()).getId();
            System.out.println(button);

            if(button.equals("play")){
                clickedButton.setDisable(true);
                play();
            }
            else if (button.equals("topLeft")) {
                out.print("MOVE0");
                //do something
            } else if (button.equals("topRight")) {
                //do something
                out.print("MOVE2");
            } else if (button.equals("topCenter")) {
                //do something
                out.print("MOVE1");
            } else if (button.equals("midLeft")) {
                //do something
                out.print("MOVE3");
            } else if (button.equals("midCenter")) {
                //do something
                out.print("MOVE4");
            } else if (button.equals("midRight")) {
                //do something
                out.print("MOVE5");
            } else if (button.equals("botLeft")) {
                //do something
                out.print("MOVE6");
            } else if (button.equals("botMid")) {
                //do something
                out.print("MOVE7");
            } else if (button.equals("botRight")) {
                //do something
                out.print("MOVE8");
            }
    }
    public void play() throws IOException {
        String response;
        try {
            connectToServer();
            response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Send to server" + in);

                    char mark = response.charAt(7);
                    System.out.println("You are " + mark);

                    if (mark == 'X') {
                        icon = new ImageView(Circle);
                        opponentIcon = new ImageView(Cross);

                    } else {
                        icon = new ImageView(Cross);
                        opponentIcon = new ImageView(Circle);
                    }
                    //frame.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe - Player " + mark);


            while (true) {
                response = in.readLine();
                if (response != null) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    if (response.startsWith("VALID_MOVE")) {
                        int location = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(5));
                        if (location == 0) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        } else if (location == 1) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        } else if (location == 2) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        } else if (location == 3) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        } else if (location == 4) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        } else if (location == 5) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        } else if (location == 6) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        } else if (location == 7) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        } else if (location == 7) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        } else if (location == 8) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, icon);
                        }
                    } else if (response.startsWith("OPPONENT_MOVED")) {
                        int location = Integer.parseInt(response.substring(15));
                        if (location == 0) {
                            handleButtonClick(topLeft, opponentIcon);
                        } else if (location == 1) {
                            handleButtonClick(topCenter, opponentIcon);
                        } else if (location == 2) {
                            handleButtonClick(topRight, opponentIcon);
                        } else if (location == 3) {
                            handleButtonClick(midLeft, opponentIcon);
                        } else if (location == 4) {
                            handleButtonClick(midCenter, opponentIcon);
                        } else if (location == 5) {
                            handleButtonClick(midRight, opponentIcon);
                        } else if (location == 6) {
                            handleButtonClick(botLeft, opponentIcon);
                        } else if (location == 7) {
                            handleButtonClick(botMid, opponentIcon);
                        } else if (location == 8) {
                            handleButtonClick(botRight, opponentIcon);
                        }
                    } else if (response.startsWith("VICTORY")) {
                        //messageLabel.setText("You win");
                        break;
                    } else if (response.startsWith("DEFEAT")) {
                        //messageLabel.setText("You lose");
                        break;
                    } else if (response.startsWith("TIE")) {
                        //messageLabel.setText("You tied");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            out.println("QUIT");
        }
        finally {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
    public void handleButtonClick(Button button, ImageView mark){
        button.setGraphic(mark);
    }

public static void connectToServer(){
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e + " fuck");
    }
}
```

}

This is my server class:

```
public class Server {
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static ArrayList<Socket> sockets;
private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777);

        sockets = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Player " + i + " connected");
            sockets.add(socket);

        }
            Game game = new Game();
            System.out.println("Created game, waiting for players to connect");

            Game.PlayerHandler playerX = game.new PlayerHandler(sockets.remove(sockets.size()-1), 'X');
            Game.PlayerHandler playerO = game.new PlayerHandler(sockets.remove(sockets.size()-1), 'O');
            game.currentPlayer = playerX;

            playerX.start();
            playerO.start();
            System.out.println("Game started");

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}

class Game{

    private PlayerHandler[] board = {
            null, null, null,
            null, null, null,
            null, null, null
    };
    PlayerHandler currentPlayer;

    public boolean isFull(){
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            if(board[i] == null){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public boolean hasWinner() {
        if (checkHorizontalWin() || checkVerticalWin() || checkDiagonalWin()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean checkHorizontalWin() {
        if (board[0] != null && board[0] == board[1] && board[0] == board[2]) {
            return true;
        } else if(board[3] != null && board[3] == board[4] && board[3] == board[5]) {
            return true;
        } else if(board[6] != null && board[6] == board[7] && board[6] == board[8]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkVerticalWin() {
        if (board[0] != null && board[0] == board[3] && board[0] == board[6]) {
            return true;
        } else if(board[1] != null && board[1] == board[4] && board[1] == board[7]) {
            return true;
        } else if(board[2] != null && board[2] == board[5] && board[2] == board[8]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkDiagonalWin() {
        if (board[0] != null && board[0] == board[4] && board[0] == board[8]) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[2] != null && board[2] == board[4] && board[2] == board[6]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean move(PlayerHandler player, int location) { //A player moves based on their assigned Piece
        System.out.println("Player moved at location " + location);
        if(board[location]==null){
            board[location] = player;
            currentPlayer = currentPlayer.opponent;
            currentPlayer.opponentMoved(location);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    class PlayerHandler extends Thread{
        char mark;
        private String name;
        private Socket socket;

        PlayerHandler opponent;
        BufferedReader in;
        PrintWriter out;

        public PlayerHandler(Socket socket, char mark) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.mark = mark;
            try{
                // initialize input and output streams
                in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("WELCOME" + mark);
            } catch(IOException e){

            }
        }

        public void setOpponent(PlayerHandler opponent){
            this.opponent = opponent;

        }

        public void opponentMoved(int location){
            out.println("OPPONENT_MOVED" + location);
            out.println(
                    hasWinner() ? "DEFEAT" : isFull() ? "TIE" : "");
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                if (mark == 'X') {
                    out.println("MESSAGE Your move");
                }

                while (true) {
                    String command = in.readLine();
                    if (command != null) {

                        if (command.startsWith("MOVE")) {
                            int location = Integer.parseInt(command.substring(5));
                            System.out.println(location);
                            if (move(this, location)) {
                                out.println("VALID_MOVE" + "location");
                                out.println(hasWinner() ? "VICTORY"
                                        : isFull() ? "TIE"
                                        : "");
                            } else {
                                out.println("MESSAGE ?");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Player died: " + e);
            } finally {
                try {socket.close();} catch(IOException e){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the important part of your code to the question

Comment: update: the video doesn't show my mouses pinwheel spinning after the client connects to the server because of the screen recorder I was using

Comment: Added TicTacToeController.java class and Server.java class

Comment: @tung Added TicTacToeController.java class and Server.java class

Comment: I believe the issue is after the the first button gets pushed the client is no longer waiting for another button pushed.

Comment: Update: After playing around with the code for a while I chalked the issue up to AsyncTasks. Because JavaFX threads have to be manually dealt with I've been having issues.